# uCommerce AppHostBase.Instance has already been set

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6, umbraco-ucommerce

I am trying to upgrade my umbraco project (version 4.11.10) with uCommerce (version 3.2.3.13009) to umbraco (version 6.0) with ucommerce (for version of umbraco). but when I run the upgrade package of uCommerce after upgrading umbroco project to version 6.0. I get the following error:

"AppHostBase.Instance has already been set"

Please advice what should be done in this regard?